# How to stop TabView from reloading entire view on @StateObject changes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a variable within my `@StateObject` that is used to show new message notifications. It is updated periodically from my backend (push noti).
The problem is that once this variable updates the badge, it will pull the user out of other tabs unexpectedly (i.e. reloads the entire `TabView` and takes them to the first tab). I want the notification badge to update without interfering with what the user is doing. I've tried using `equatable()`, but to no avail. It seems that `TabView` reloads *everything* on state object changes. Is there a way to only reload the tab labels? any help will be appreciated.

`ContentView.swift`:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tab: UInt = 0
    @StateObject var messenger: MessagingViewModel = MessagingViewModel()
    @State var firstAppear = true
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.white) 
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tab) {
            HomeMarket(tab: $tab)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Market", systemImage: "house.fill")
                }.tag(0)
            
            AddItems(tab: $tab)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                }.tag(1)
            
            MessageList(tab: $tab)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Messages", systemImage: "envelope.fill")
                }
                .tag(2)
                .badge(messenger.newMsgCount)
        }
        .accentColor(Color("AccentColor"))
        .onAppear() {
            if firstAppear {
                messenger.getAllMessages()
                firstAppear = false
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(messenger)
        
    }
}
```

`MessengerViewModel.swift`: (shortened for SO. Even this small sample causes the same issue)

```
class MessagingViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var newMsgCount = 0

   init(){// connect socket...}

   func setUpChatListener() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.manager.defaultSocket.on("Private Message") { data, ack in
                do {
                    self.newMsgCount += 1
                    //do what ever else I need to do with the chat...
                    
                } catch let err {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've really hit a roadblock with this one. Am I going to have to use Apple's push system? I find it odd that I can't just reload the little icon to show the new message count rather than reloading the entire thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by a mismatch of your `tab` type (which you've defined as `UInt`) and the `.tag` modifier that you've added to each tab item, which Swift is interpreting as an `Int`, when you write `.tag(0)`.

You can fix this two ways. Unless you *really* need it to be a `UInt`, you could change to `Int` (including all of the bindings in the views that you're sending it to):

```
struct HomeMarket : View {
    @Binding var tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("HomeMarket")
    }
}

struct AddItems : View {
    @Binding var tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Add")
    }
}

struct MessageList : View {
    @Binding var tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Messages")
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tab: Int = 0
    @StateObject var messenger: MessagingViewModel = MessagingViewModel()
    @State var firstAppear = true
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tab) {
            HomeMarket(tab: $tab)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Market", systemImage: "house.fill")
                }.tag(0)
            
            AddItems(tab: $tab)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                }.tag(1)
            
            MessageList(tab: $tab)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Messages", systemImage: "envelope.fill")
                }
                .tag(2)
                .badge(messenger.newMsgCount)
        }
        .onAppear() {
            if firstAppear {
                messenger.getAllMessages()
                firstAppear = false
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: tab, perform: { newValue in
            print("Tab changed: ", newValue)
        })
        .environmentObject(messenger)
    }
}

class MessagingViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var newMsgCount = 0
   func getAllMessages() {
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
           self.newMsgCount += 1
       }
   }
}
```

Or, you could explicitly use `UInt` in your `.tag` modifiers:

```
TabView(selection: $tab) {
    HomeMarket(tab: $tab)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Market", systemImage: "house.fill")
        }.tag(0 as UInt)
    
    AddItems(tab: $tab)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus.circle")
        }.tag(1 as UInt)
    
    MessageList(tab: $tab)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Messages", systemImage: "envelope.fill")
        }
        .tag(2 as UInt)
        .badge(messenger.newMsgCount)
}
```

---

Explanation:

`tag()` is a relatively common source of issues since the compiler doesn't warn you if the type doesn't match what you provide in `selection:` (it would be nice if there were a compiler or linter warning about it).

The reloading happens because when you tap to load another tab, it doesn't actually end up setting the `tab` variable (since the types don't match). Then, upon another state change (like an update coming from your `StateObject`) the system uses the `@State` variable to determine what tab it should be on. Since it was never updated to anything other than 0, it looks like it 'resets' it's state, but in actuality, it *thinks* it's going to the place that you want (as represented by your `@State` variable).

Comment: just tested it and you are right. If you have time, could you explain how you knew that was the issue? I had been struggling with this for about 2 days, I don't think I would've thought of that. Is it due to some kind of conversion going on in the background that is redrawing the screen with each conversion/cast?

Comment: Added an explanation at the bottom.